# dotnet core healthchecks postgres connectionstring query

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core

im learning dotnet core and trying to add a healthcheck to an api i got working. I have added the `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.NpgSql` nuget and added to startup.cs:

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
   .AddNpgSql(connectionString);
```

but im getting the error:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'MovieApp.ConnectionString' to 'string' MovieApp
```

my connectionstring in `ConfigureServices` is:

```
var connectionString = new ConnectionString(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```

which uses `ConnectionString.cs`

```
namespace MovieApp
{
    public sealed class ConnectionString
    {
        public ConnectionString(string value) => Value = value;
        public string Value { get; }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AddNpgSql(string)` accepts string type of parameter while you pass a `ConnectionString` type , try to use `connectionString.Value` instead:

```
var connectionString = new ConnectionString(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
services.AddHealthChecks().AddNpgSql(connectionString.Value);
```